# Nakama is running from command line using docker-compose up command but unable to access it from URL http://127.0.0.1:7350/ What can be the issue?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, nakama

Nakama is running from command line using docker-compose up command but unable to access it from URL What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

you must set host network for your service:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nakama:
        network_mode: "host"
```